# sending POST in ruby?

Tags: ruby, post

any good library to send POST headers in ruby ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
require 'net/http'

postData = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://thewebsite.net'), {'postKey'=>'postValue'})

puts postData.body
```

Answer (score 6):

The standard library [Net::HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) is pretty straightforward and handles `POST`.

From the docs:

```
response = http.post('/cgi-bin/search.rb', 'query=foo')

# using block
File.open('result.txt', 'w') {|f|
  http.post('/cgi-bin/search.rb', 'query=foo') do |str|
    f.write str
  end
}
```

For more detailed examples of how to use Net::HTTP, see August Lilleaas's [Net::HTTP cheat sheet repository on Github](http://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet).

Comment: You don't say what the `http` object is, or how to get it

Comment: @Pablo That's correct; I don't. As I said, I grabbed that example directly from Net::HTTP's documentation (which I linked to). I assumed that the OP would follow up by learning how to use Net::HTTP. (Teach a person to fish...)

Comment: Nice job linking the cheatsheet though... I had edited that but rolled it back 'cause it seemed like too intrusive. Best answer overall = +10

Answer (score 1):

`Net::HTTP` as mentioned, the curl wrapper [Curb](http://curb.rubyforge.org/), or [HTTParty](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). Depending on what you are trying to do, they may be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of HTTP libraries in Ruby.  There's the standard [net/http](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) and [libcurl bindings](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ruby/).  But there are also a lot of high-level libraries to consume web services such as ActiveResource and [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/).  Depends on what you want to do.  Maybe you can update your question with more information?