# In Rails 3.2 emailer, how "include" contents of a css file into the HTML for the email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

When my Rails app emails someone, I need to include the contents of one of the CSS files we also use in our application layout file.

It's can't be a normal stylesheet 'link' to the css file, it needs to actually load the contents of the css into the `head` section of the outgoing email's html view.

How can I tell an email view to 'import' or 'include' the contents of the css file:
/assets/stylesheets/foo.css

Comment: What you're asking for is still not possible. You might however want to take a look at the following gem https://github.com/Mange/roadie. This gem parses your file, and hard includes every style you're using

Comment: I believe you would need to either inline the css or use gems like `Roadie`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6230228/326543) has more such gems.

Comment: It's not a question about in-line CSS, it's a question about the best way to use the SAME css file in multiple emails. I'm not currently using mailer layouts, but that looks like the way to go if there's no "include" statement available.